# Swagger Documentar dois status 404 no mesmo recurso é possível?

Tags: spring-boot, restful, documentação, swagger

Olá.

Estou usado Spring Boot no desenvolvimento de uma API REST e o Swagger/OpenAPI 3 para gerar a documentação dos recursos. A documentação está sendo gerada por meio de anotações em cada um dos recursos.

Estou enfrentando um problema com a documentação. Tenho um recurso que precisa localizar um item e caso não seja encontrado uma exceção é lançada e o retorno 404 é gerado.

Porém, esse mesmo recurso pode ter uma exceção laçada em uma consulta diferente, por outro campo, que também gera o status 404.

Tentei cadastrar os dois status 404 na documentação, mas quando ela é gerada, na página não aparecem os dois 404 e sim apenas um deles.

O recurso está documentado de forma similar a esse exemplo:

```
@Operation(responses = {
        @ApiResponse(responseCode= 200, description = "Sucesso"),
        @ApiResponse(responseCode= 404, description = "Cliente Não Cadastrado"),
        @ApiResponse(responseCode= 404, description = "Nenhum Item Encontrado")
})
@GetMapping("/clientes/{id_cliente}/item/{id_item}")
public ResponseEntity<?> criar(@PathVariable Long id_item, 
                               @PathVariable Long id_cliente) {
  // código omitido
}
```

O recurso tem dois parametros. O cliente pode não existir, por isso, uso o 404 com uma mensagem especifica para esse caso. Mas o cliente pode existir, mas o item não, por isso, outro 404 com outra mensagem especifica.

Porém, como dito, o swagger não está adicionando na documentação os dois 404, ele adiciona apenas 1 deles e omite o outro. Saberiam como resolver essa questão?

Comment: Onde está anotado `@Operation(responses = {` não seria `@ApiResponses(value = {` ? Você pode usar [oneOf](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/oneof-anyof-allof-not/) para especificar [esquemas alternativos para a resposta](https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-two-responses-one-response-code) e documentar possíveis dependências na resposta. No entanto, até o momento [**não há como vincular esquemas específicos a determinadas combinações de parâmetros**](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-responses/).

Comment: Oi @Augusto, estou usando a versão 3 do Swagger/OpenAPI, ela permite usar `@Operation` ou `@ApiResponses`. Vou dar uma olhada nos links que me sugeriu, obrigado.

Comment: Se chegar a uma conclusão diferente da que o apresentei por favor poste aqui.

Comment: Infelizmente as suas sugestões não serviram para o contexto que tenho. Como retorno o mesmo objeto de erro, apenas com as mensagens diferentes, não rolou. A não ser que eu mudasse o objeto de erro. Me deram uma sugestão para criar status code diferentes, tipo 604, 605 para esse tipo de operação. Não sei se é uma solução interessante, estou estudando a possibilidade.